# String manipulation in params[:something]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

`params[:svn_path]` is returning an URL like this

```
http://svn.repos.mywebsite.com/testingtitle.documents
```

Now I need to get only the last part of the url that is `testingtitle`.

How to we get it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://rubular.com/r/irmRo84IFF

Comment: @apneadiving so cool, you helped me learn more. It should be an answer.

Comment: @KienThanh: posted as answer then!

Comment: @apneadiving - I learnt something today thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Uri module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) of ruby

```
uri = URI.parse("http://svn.repos.mywebsite.com/testingtitle.documents")

path = uri.path #"/testingtitle.documents"
path_with_no_slash = path.gsub("/", "") #"testingtitle.documents"
array = path_with_no_slash.split(".") #["testingtitle", "documents"]
result = array[0] #"testingtitle"
```

Comment: Careful with the `split`: If the filename contains multiple dots (*my.file.txt*) this will return only the first part (*my*).

Comment: This is where it's good to reuse File's `basename` and `extname`. `extname` only returns the last `.ext` in a filename, so we don't need to split or worry about getting too many. Actually, I prefer/recommend using File's methods for manipulating paths if possible, because they're well tested, or Pathname if you want all of File and FileUtil's methods bundled in one module.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a regexp to get what you expect.

[Here is a good example](http://rubular.com/r/irmRo84IFF).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `File.basename`; for example

```
url = "http://svn.repos.mywebsite.com/testingtitle.documents"
ext = File.extname(url)
result = File.basename(url, ext)
```

The second argument to `basename` takes care of removing the file extension. `result` will hold the desired result.

Comment: Clip the extension using `File.extname` as the second parameter to `File.basename`.

Comment: @theTinMan Ingenious! I took the liberty to incorporate that in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

**With proper URI parser -**

This will give you last part of the url as you have stated.

```
require 'uri'

url       = "http://svn.repos.mywebsite.com/testingtitle.documents"    
last_part = URI(url).path.split('/').last # => testingtitle.documents
```

However the output you have provided will require a little more manipulation on the last part, i.e. split on `.`

```
last_part.split('.').first # => testingtitle
```

**Simple string manipulation -**

```
url = "http://svn.repos.mywebsite.com/testingtitle.documents"
url.split('/').last.split('.').first # => testingtitle
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`params[:svn_path].match(/.*\.com\/(.*)\..*$/)[1]`

```
1.9.3p194 :009 > params[:svn_path].match(/.*\.com\/(.*)\..*$/)[1]
 => "testingtitle"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `URI` to parse this url:

```
url = URI.parse('http://svn.repos.mywebsite.com/testingtitle.documents')
```

which will give you an object with these variables:

```
url.instance_variables #> [ :@scheme, :@user, :@password, :@host, :@port, :@path, :@query, :@opaque, :@registry, :@fragment, :@parser ]
```

and then just use a simple regular expression on `path` component like this:

```
url.path.match(/\w+/) #> #<MatchData "testingtitle">
```

which will match the first occurrence of any word characters (not including / or .)

Answer (score 1):

`Regexp` + `groups`

```
url = 'http://svn.repos.mywebsite.com/testingtitle.documents'
puts url.match(/com\/([a-z]+)/)[1]
#=> testingtitle
```